# How to return source table name when using a UNION?

Tags: sql

If I use a UNION to select columns from 5 tables, then select a particular value from the results, how can I determine which table that value came from?

Comment: Will you please elaborate or explain with an example what you are asking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Supply table names in a column along other columns you are pulling:

```
SELECT
  'table1' AS tablename,
  other columns
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'table2' AS tablename,
  other columns
FROM table2

UNION ALL

…
```

Comment: i know how to union i want to know like i have some value in particular column of any of 4 table and it show result i want to return table name where that element is located

Comment: @Arshpreet: Not sure I understand what you are asking now. My point was to show how to supply table names, not how to union multiple selects (I guessed you knew that already). You can see in the above example that, in addition to other columns being retrieved, the result set will also have a column called `tablename`. This way every row in the output will contain the name of the table it has been obtained from.

Answer (score 5):

add a column to the result list that says which table the data is coming from. e.g.:

```
select 'table1' tableName,
       columnA,
       columnB
from table1
union
select 'table2' tableName,
       columnC,
       columnD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, 'Table 1' FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT columnA, columnB, 'Table 2' FROM table2
```

This will add a column which displays which table the data comes from.
Works in Oracle atleast...

Answer (score 0):

```
select col 1, col 2, 'users' as table_name from users
union all
select col 1, col 2, 'vendors' as table_name from vendors;
```

'table_name' will contains the source names.

Hope this works